# Boxes box.new are duplicated, cannot delete old ones

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I store bar indexes in an  array based on a criteria and at last bar i want to draw boxes.
At first load the number of boxes is correct.
[image]

But after i Forward next candles in replay, it seems the old boxes are not deleted and i have many duplicates.
[image]

How can i have the number of boxes equal with the number of array.size and get rid of duplicate boxes ?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
indicator("boxes - test", overlay = true, max_lines_count=500, max_boxes_count=500, max_labels_count=500,  max_bars_back = 4999)


// set time range to test 
daysBack = input(1)

_MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
lastBarDate = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), hour(timenow), minute(timenow), second(timenow))
thisBarDate = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second)
daysLeft = math.floor((lastBarDate - thisBarDate) / _MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY)
inRange = daysLeft <= daysBack

bgcolor( inRange ? color.new(color.gray, 95) : na )


// store all bar_index in array 
var arr_green_candles_bar_indexes = array.new_int()

if inRange
     and close[1] > open[1] and high[1] > high[2]

    array.push(arr_green_candles_bar_indexes, bar_index - 1 )




// at last bar delete all boxes and draw again all boxes 
var box box_1 = na 

if bar_index == last_bar_index 

    box.delete(box_1) // tried no succes
    box_1 := na  // tried no succes

    for i = 0 to array.size(arr_green_candles_bar_indexes) - 1

        bar_index_val = array.get(arr_green_candles_bar_indexes, i)

        box_1 := box.new(
                 left = bar_index_val, 
                 top = high, 
                 right = bar_index_val + 1, 
                 bottom = low,
                 xloc = xloc.bar_index, 
                 extend = extend.none,
                 bgcolor = color.new(color.blue, 70),
                 border_color = color.new(color.white, 100)
                 )


a_allBoxes = box.all
a_allBoxes_size = array.size(a_allBoxes)


var label lbl = na
label.delete(lbl)
lbl := label.new (barstate.islast ? bar_index  : na, 
     y = close, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_index, 
     yloc = yloc.belowbar, 
     style = label.style_label_left,
     size = size.large,
     textalign = text.align_left,
     color = color.new(color.green, 0),
     textcolor = color.new(color.white, 0),
     text = "" + str.tostring( a_allBoxes_size )
     )  


var label lbl2 = na
label.delete(lbl2)
lbl2 := label.new (barstate.islast ? bar_index  : na, 
     y=close, 
     xloc=xloc.bar_index, 
     yloc=yloc.abovebar, 
     style = label.style_label_left,
     size = size.large,
     color = color.new(color.aqua, 60),
     textcolor = color.new(color.black, 0),
     textalign = text.align_left,
     text = "" + str.tostring( arr_green_candles_bar_indexes  )
     )
```